# WP7 dynamic ListBox with GPS value

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, gps, windows-phone-7.1

I'll try to explain my problem ... Sorry for the English translation to Google.

I'd like to dynamically display the values ​​in a gps listBox

I have a class that stock values ​​gps:

```
public class LocationManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

another with the Name and Value:

```
public class GpsItem: INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and a third class:

```
 public class GpsItems: ObservableCollection<GpsItem>
```

My listbox which has ItemsSource as my third class

```
ListBox.ItemsSource = new GpsItems();
```

xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" Background="#BF000000" Tap="LsbAllCases_Tap">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,10" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode="OneWay"}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode="OneWay"}"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The value displayed in the execution but are not dynamic.

I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface with:

```
    // Declare the PropertyChanged event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // NotifyPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
    // source property that is being updated.
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I do not know what to do ... HELP
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [How to: Get Data from the Location Service for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and the [Location Service Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is very useful too.

It has helped me a lot to understand how use the GPS

Answer (score 0):

Your `Name` and `Value` should be like that to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
    private string name;
    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really update `Name&Value` properties dynamically or issue while update happening? Set breakpoint in `setter` in `Debugger`

Comment: apparently, Name & Value never be updated in the ObservableCollection